# JSON Web Token Bearer Grant giving " Invalid_grant" as response in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I have taken the sample code from Docusign SDK  to exchange token for user authentication. Followed all the steps given in the document. Provided valid user id, Integration key and configured private and public key correctly. It was working fine till last Friday. Is some thing happening today in docusign demo account?. I am getting " Invalid_grant " as response.

## JWTLoginTest:

Exception: com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting an access token: {**"error":"invalid_grant"**}

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken

Comment: Please show the request. The example request on that page is `curl --data "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=eyJhb..."
          --request POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token`. Do you have `grant-type:jwt-bearer` in yours?

Comment: we are adding below values in the request. "assertion" and "grant_type" as like below .form.add("assertion", assertion);
    form.add("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");

Comment: Try it first using curl in terminal and then do it with code. You may also ask docusign for support.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you start with one of the new JWT Grant flow examples in the DocuSign github organization:

- [C# for .NET Core](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-csharp-jwt-core)
- [C# for .NET Framework](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-csharp-jwt-framework)
- [PHP](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-php-jwt)
- [Java](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-java-jwt)
- [Node.JS](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-node-jwt)
- [Python](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-python-jwt)
- [Ruby](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-ruby-jwt)